# Looking for `locationbar2` similar extenstion for Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

As a developer, I like the way I can click url's sub-sections so as to browse around my web. In firefox I can do that easily with support from Firefox's extension `Locationbar2` ([link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locationbar%C2%B2/)).

I've searched Chrome's extension gallery but failed. Do you know any of that exists?

Answer (score 3):

[URL Linkifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mcmkleldnpaenneepdiiamfcpnaemejg) is the closest I can get to mimic locationbar2's clickable URL segments.